# How to check SetBinding method updates the property value?

Tags: c#, win-universal-app

I have to check whether SetBinding method is updating the specific property value.

I have used SetBinding like below,

```
 var binding = new Binding();
        binding.Path = new PropertyPath("NullCheck");
        binding.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;
        binding.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
        uiElement.SetBinding(CheckBox.IsCheckedProperty, binding);
```

Here how can I check the CheckBox property is updated or not based on binding path?

I have checked uiElement.IsChecked value once I have set binding using SetBinding method as coded above.

But this always returns false. Anyone suggest a way to check the updated value?

Comment: Are you not getting any Binding exception? Is NullCheck property is under the DataContext of ToggleButton?

Comment: @LovetoCode No. I'm not getting any binding exception. Also have checked this for CheckBox.IsChecked property.

Comment: Is NullCheck Property has PropertyChanged event implemented? Can you post the ViewModel code where you declared NullCheck and the xaml code

Comment: @LovetoCode ok. Will check and modify. Thanks for your valuable time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Here how can I check the CheckBox property is updated or not based on binding path?

If the `checkBoxElement.IsChecked` value has been updated correctly, `checkBoxElement.IsChecked` will be the right value and you will see the CheckBoxElement on page checked/unchecked.

According to your posted codes. I think you forget to set the binding source. You can do this by: `binding.Source={Your Binding Source Object\Variable}`.

And if your binding source is an object(let's say `myObj`), you want to bind `isChecked` Property to `myObj.BooleanProperty`(The BooleanProperty should contain get set). The `binding.Path` should be set to "BooleanProperty".

If your binding source is a variable, you don't need to set `binding.Path` or you can let it be an empty string("").

Here is a basic demo that you can refer to: [SetBindingSample](https://github.com/elvisxia/SetBindingSample)

And in your codes I also noticed you maybe want to create a two-way-binding. It needs implementation of [INotifyPropertyChanged Interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.data.inotifypropertychanged.aspx)

Comment: Thank you for your explanation